# Inverting perspective projection doesn't yield frustum?

Tags: rendering, geometry, perspective, camera-matrix

I have a cube with 8 vertices representing the $[-1,1]^3$ cube vulkan uses for device coordinates.

The perspective projection matrix takes a frustum and maps it onto this cube. It thus makes sense that the inverse of this transformation applied to the cube should yield the frustum.

To that effect I have this little snippet:

```cpp
    Eigen::Matrix4d perspective_mat = Perspective(80.f, 1.f, 0.1f, node.normal.norm()).cast<double>(); // delete
    HMesh<VertexData> cube("cube.obj");                                                                // delete
    for (auto &vert : cube.VertexDataD())
    {
        const auto &pos = vert.position;
        auto tmp = ((perspective_mat).inverse().eval() * Edvec4(pos.x(), pos.y(), pos.z(), 1));

        vert.position = {tmp.x() / tmp[3], tmp.y() / tmp[3], tmp.z() / tmp[3]};
     }
```

Well this little guy creates this thing:

[image]

Which does not look like a frustum.

What am I doing wrong? I know it's not a coding error in the sense I trust all my functions, but I might have a math error.

Comment: have you mixed degree with radiant? Or what does the "80.f" in the first line represent?

Comment: "*cube with 8 vertices representing the [−1,1]3 cube vulkan uses for device coordinates.*" Vulkan's standard device coordinates [are not a cube](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap24.html#vertexpostproc-viewport).